# Collapsible tree in javascript/jquery

Tags: html

I am interested in knowing how the following link is able to list items/links in the form of an explorable tree - I am referring to the PAGE TREE structure in the left hand side div/section.

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=637

I want to know how what all things/items/urls that have to appear under the parent node are determined. I mean how does this happen?.

Any inputs are most welcome.

Thanks, 
Pavan.

Comment: with a less than a minute research you can find a million and one plugins for that. coding it from scratch is not hard either.

Comment: you could have just right clicked on the links and inspected the code.. you could have found the exact plugin they are using

Answer (score 0):

What Guille and Banana said is correct. Plus if you use the Inspect option in your browser while testing out the tree, it'll show part of what they are using is

```
style="display:none"
```

and

```
style="display:block"
```

That's a hint to get you started but yeah like they said, lots of plugins out there to use or ways for you to program it.

Also as a quick suggestion, Bootstrap comes with a tree option along with many other features.